# List of babel shorthands

Tags: babel, shorthands

Is it possible to find list of shorthands in general?

I am using package babel with "czech" option, and as much as I love that it works great for me, pretty often I hit upon errors when working with TikZ or pgfplots by having "-" as active shorthand. I know that I can disable it entirely in package option, but that would disable hyphenation (I think, among other things).

So far I was not able to find list of shorthands introduced by babel. Is there some place, where are they listed?

Or even better, is it possible to display currently active shorthands in document?

Comment: As to the latter question, see the log file and search for messages like `Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 561.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Should be a comment, really, but).. About the shorthand list: in the babel manual, page 13, you have this:

[image: Screenshot of babel manual]

And no, disabling shorthand will **not** disable hyphenation! (I hope...)