# Dates are not being formatted

Tags: date, genealogytree

I'm using the `genealogytree` package to make a nice family tree. No matter what I do, however, I haven't managed to get the dates to format properly. For example, I'd expect the bottom node to say 22.7.1877 for the date of birth based on the `d.m.yyyy` format. I wrote the optional arguments for \genealogytree following the manual and some formatting routine seems to be called, as the `(caAD)` calendar is interpreted properly, but the actual dates are printed as-is. Reasonably minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[
processing=database, database format=medium no marriage,
tcbset={male/.style={colframe=blue,colback=blue!5}, female/.style={colframe=red,colback=red!5}},
name font=\bfseries, place text={\newline}{}, date format=d.m.yyyy,
label database options={place text={(}{)}},
label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black},
]{
    parent[family database={marriage={1874-02-16}{Zalužany}}]{
        g[male]{name={Josef Zelenka}, birth={1877-07-22}{Zalužany}}
        parent[family database={marriage={1848-03-06}{Kozárovice}}]{
            g[male]{name={František Zelenka}, birth={1850-04-12}{Kozárovice}, death={1893-04-08}{Kozárovice}}
            p[male]{name={Tomáš Zelenka}, birth={1812-12-29}{Kozárovice}, death={1890-03-10}{Kozárovice}}
            p[female]{name={Anna Peterková}, birth={1817-11-14}{Kozárovice}, death={1890-06-16}{Kozárovice}}
        }
        parent[family database={marriage={1842-02-06}{Nevězice}}]{
            g[female]{name={Marie Říhová}, birth={1850-06-17}{Zalužany}, death={1889-08-09}{Kozárovice}}
            p[male]{name={Josef Říha}, birth={1819-08-04}{Vrábsko}}
            p[female]{name={Josefa Skopečková}, birth={(caAD)1824}{Nevězice}}
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles to:
[image: Minimal example above as compiled by pdfLaTeX]

The `genealogytree` package version is `2.1.0`. I'm using pdflatex, output of `pdflatex -version`:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

Big thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: It doesn't happen without `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` so there seems to be some interaction with how that redefines data formats.

Comment: Oh, good observation - it didn't occur to me. Is there a chance that the genealogytree package might attempt to get Czech names of the months based on the Czech babel and output the unformatted dates due to a failure of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As identified in a comment the problem is caused by Babel with the Czech option. This is because that option enables `-` as a shorthand (see for example [List of babel shorthands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509421/list-of-babel-shorthands)). A shorthand is a character or character combination that makes it easy to enter language-specific punctuation or disable ligatures, which works by turning the character into a LaTeX command. However, date parsing in `genealogytree` depends on the hyphen being a regular character.

You can switch the shorthand off inside `tikzpicture` environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/before}{\shorthandoff{-}}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This has resolved my issue. Thank you very much for your answer!